# How do I use jQuery to load my advertisements?

Tags: jquery

Some ads on my website are slowing down load time. How can I use jquery to load the ad code while the page is loading?

I tried something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    advertisement();

    function advertisement() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/advertisement.php",
            data: "type=googleads",
            beforeSend: function () {
                $("#advertisement").html('Loading ...');
            },
            cache: false,
            success: function (a) {
                $("#advertisement").html(a);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

But it redirects me to the ads company site instead of showing the ads.

Is it possible?

Comment: did you solve your problem? what is the `advertisement.php` returning?

Comment: not really, i already moved past it :(

Comment: so take my comment as a second chance to solve your problem! I want to know some exact returns of your `advertisement.php` to rebuild your application and test your problems :)

Answer (score 2):

I can see nothing wrong in your code. If you read the [Ajax Description of jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) it defines a attribute called `dataType`which is by default: **Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html)**. So by default it should not use text, it should use html. This means that it

> Returns HTML as plain text; included script tags are evaluated when inserted in the DOM

if you want to load ad code it is often just JavaScript without need of html and so you should use `dataType="script"` which

> evaluates the response as JavaScript and returns it as plain text. Disables caching by appending a query string parameter, "_=[TIMESTAMP]", to the URL unless the cache option is set to true. Note: This will turn POSTs into GETs for remote-domain requests.

As far as you do not give as an example of your `advertisement.php` we can not say if your loaded code is correct... I have no experience of Google Ads as your code template seems to load, so if the error is there, sry :)

Comment: Hey thanks man for trying to solve this but however i don't have the php codes anymore and the project is already long overdue.